# WebView console shows errors on android < 4.0 | (JVectorMap)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, jvectormap

I have an issue that's a bit strange... I have a server API where I've installed JVectorMap javascripts to show some stats on maps. it's very simple I just have to set the url to the webview like this:

(WebView Config)

```
WebView wv = (WebView)lv_header.findViewById(R.id.result_webview);

WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

WebView method I call to show map

```
private void setWebView(String countryCode) {
wv.loadUrl( MyApplication.API_URL_SERVER_PRODUCTION+"/query/"+getIdFromPos(array_id, posInArray)+"/map/"+countryCode);
}
```

On Android 4.x > will show ok everything is ok but under 4.x I have this log; (And the webView is blank):

```
E/Web Console(8411): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLDocument> has no method: 'createStyleSheet' at http://www.miwebsite.com/static/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js:7
```

Method 'createStyleSheet' it's in the "jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" file...

Example of a map ==> [Click Here](http://test.queryday.icustomsolutions.com/query/115/map/es)

Answer (score 0):

In jVectorMap uncompressed there is a call to `document.createStyleSheet()` javascript function at line #182:

```
jvm.VMLElement.initializeVML = function () {
        try {
            document.namespaces.rvml || document.namespaces.add("rvml", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"), jvm.VMLElement.prototype.createElement = function (e) {
                return document.createElement("<rvml:" + e + ' class="rvml">')
            }
        } catch (e) {
            jvm.VMLElement.prototype.createElement = function (e) {
                return document.createElement("<" + e + ' xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:vml" class="rvml">')
            }
        }
        document.createStyleSheet().addRule(".rvml", "behavior:url(#default#VML)"), jvm.VMLElement.VMLInitialized = !0
    }
```

The function is not jVectorMap specific, is specific to the javascript implementation in the IE browser, until IE 11. It's possible you're using a browser that doesn't support this (maybe you're sending the IE user agent string from your Android browser).

Use [this uncompressed jVectorMap](http://jsfiddle.net/g9uFe/) (copy, paste and save it in a file and use it to replace the minified jVectorMap you currently are using) and see what line is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help! the line that gives me this issue is 524 that says ==>  if (!jvm.WorldMap.maps[this.params.map]) throw new Error("Attempt to use map which was not loaded: " + this.params.map); what causes this problem on android < 4.0 ?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with either android or jvectormap. Most likely you're not linking to the correct map, e.g. jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js has to have  map: 'us_aea_en' or jquery-jvectormap-fr-merc-en.js has to have map: 'fr_merc_en'.

Comment: works on android 4.0> and iOS. but on android <4.0 only works if I go to a browser that's not default by android (example: Firefox)

Comment: It looks like the default browser on your 4.0 is sending the wrong user agent string. Try to reset it.